# Multiple Images From Camera Roll In Different UIImage Views - Photo Collage App

Tags: xcode, uiimageview

So this has been annoying the hell out of me. What I want to do is create a photo collage app where there are multiple image views and I will place buttons over the image views and when a user clicks the button it brings up the camera roll and you can choose an image and it places it in that image view. The problem I am having is that everytime a user chooses an image, it only places it in one image view even though I have declared more than one. The image just keeps getting replaced. Below is my code.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerTwo;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *toggleCamera;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageViewOne;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageViewTwo;
- (IBAction)buttonOne:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)buttonTwo:(id)sender;

@end
```

View Controller.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize toggleCamera;
@synthesize imageViewOne;
@synthesize imageViewTwo;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{   imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerTwo = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setImageViewOne:nil];
    [self setImageViewTwo:nil];
    [self setToggleCamera:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [imageViewOne release];
    [imageViewTwo release];
    [toggleCamera release];
    [super dealloc];
}


- (IBAction)buttonOne:(id)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    if ([self.toggleCamera isOn]) {
        imagePicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }else {
        imagePicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    }
    imagePicker.delegate=self;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

    }

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    self.imageViewOne.image=[info objectForKey:
                                    UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
} 


- (IBAction)buttonTwo:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerTwo;
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    if ([self.toggleCamera isOn]) {
        imagePicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }else {
        imagePicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    }
    imagePicker.delegate=self;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

}

-(void)imagePickerController2:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    self.imageViewTwo.image=[info objectForKey:
                             UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
}
@end
```

Suggetions??? PLEASE HELPPPP!!!

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

make an NSMutableArray where you can keep all the imageView objects.
so while getting the new image.. you can set them in the respective imageView, get its frame and replace it