# How to make Collage of Images and save image to Photo Gallery

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I am new to Image editing and i am working on a Collage Tool which can add images according to different collage shapes and make them one image and save it to Photo gallery.. I have seen the following links but i cant achieve what i want..

[Collage of images with different shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24962718/collage-of-images-with-different-shapes) and
[How to make collage of images according to different shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21619968/how-to-make-collage-of-images-according-to-different-shapes/)

Comment: I tried above links but i cant achieve what i want.. I just want to know if any other better solution is available for this kind of functionality..

Comment: Please understand that questions which just look for ready-made solutions are not welcome on SO. Please read the FAQ.

Comment: Its my first question in Stackoverflow and i dont want ready-made solution i just want ideas to solve this.

Comment: Any chance that you can let us know if the suggestion below works? I'd also be interested if you care to share any alternate solution you may have come up with...

Answer (score 0):

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31510330/how-to-efficiently-create-a-multi-row-photo-collage-from-an-array-of-images-in-s) to get a headstart. Basically I use some CG calls and CGRects to arrange a series of images into a photo collage. To save to the photo library, just do a search on SO for that topic or try using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum function. Read the quick help or the full documentation in Xcode to get tips on how to use the class. You can also Cmd-click on any type to read Apple's detailed comments on how to use specific classes in their APIs.